# create a realtime machine by assigning CPU cores to critical processes

Tags: awk, arm, process-management, real-time

I'm using an Udoo board for running two critical processes. It can run Ubuntu ARM edition and it has a Quadcore processor. I need to set the affinity of all the processes afinity running and the ones will be run to one core and associate the rest of processes to the other cores.

Is it cofigurable or I should write a python script and run it priodicaly?

It is appreciated to give me some hint how I can write this code. Because the following code fails:

```
ps -aux | awk '{print $2}' | taskset -c -p 0
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest to avoid parsing output of `ps` when possible. Use `-o` do set what columns you want to display and use process selectors to filter out those you are looking for - see `PROCESS SELECTION` chapters in the `ps(1)` man page.

As for the actual assignment, `taskset` doesn't read standard input. You probably want to use `xargs`:

```
something_that_produces_PIDs | xargs taskset -c -p
```